# crystal report dynamic column and .net

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

suppose my report has 10 column and at run time how could i show and hide column writing the code. need help.

Answer (score 4):

Fields in *Crystal Reports* are bundled using horizontal sections (Report Headers, Page Headers, Group Headers, Details, Group Footers, Page Footers, and Report Footers) and not using vertical alignments (columns). Most reports display columnar fields by aligning their horizontal positions but there is no intrinsic column-grouping in Crystal Reports.

To dynamically hide a column of fields at run-time, the **Suppress** flag can be set using a Boolean conditional formula:

- On the **Design** view, highlight all fields belonging to the column,
- right-click on one of them,
- select **Format Objects...** from the context-menu
- go to the **Common** tab,
- click on the **X-2** icon corresponding to the **Suppress** checkbox,
- the **Format Formula Editor - Suppress** window will open,
- input a formula that results to *True or False*.

At run-time, the fields will either display or not depending on the result of the formula. However, white space will still appear in the suppressed column fields' position and fields to the right of will still be positioned in the same spot. To make the columns to the right *slide* to the left, their **X-Position** needs to be dynamic as well:

- right-click one of the fields belonging to the column to the right,
- select **Size and Position...**,
- click on the **X-2** icon corresponding to the **X:** textbox,
- the **Format Formula Editor - X-Position Adjustment** window will open,
- input a formula that results to the number of *twips* to be adjusted,
- repeat for all other fields belonging to the column to the right.

A *Twip* is equivalent to 1/1440 of an inch. Since the field's position should slide to the left, the result of the formula should be negative (a positive value will slide the field to the right). For example, if the field should slide left 2 inches, then the formula result should be -2880.

Note that you'll need to incorporate the same condition on the **Suppress** for the left field into the formula for **X-Position Adjustment** of the right field:

- If the left field *is not* suppressed, then x-position adjustment of the right field should be 0.
- If the left field *is* suppressed, then x-position adjustment of the right field should be equal to the width in twips of the left field.

I haven't found any good *Crystal Reports Tips & Tricks* book yet so I can only recommend reading the **Crystal Reports User Guide** available from [SAP](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/CR2011/en/xi4_cr_usergde_en.pdf).