# Dynamic Crystal Report Showing a Number of Different Columns Each Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a table in *SQLServer* with 70 columns in it. What I want is to show 10 or more different columns each time on the `crystal report` based on the user selection columns ( the selection is based on `Textboxes` and `Comoboxes` ; this can be handled)

Example for 5 columns

The first attempt (selected columns) will be `ID,Name,Age,Address,Gender` will be on the report

The Second attempt will be `Name,Phone,Job,Salary,City` will be on the report

I am new to crystal report with another columns, can this be done in crystal report? And how ?

*PS : I'm using VS 2012 as IDE , SQL Server 2008 R2 , C# as programming Language*

Kindly help me.

Comment: New crystal reports means new instance of the same report or totally a new report

Comment: @Siva , thanks for your comment ; totally a new report

Answer (score 0):

Crystal is caching the fields in design time and you cannot add/remove columns using runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
so ; i cannot do it with crystal report !

Comment: You cannot! If you have few possible combinations of fields you can create different sections inside the reports and hide all except the one with the right combination.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

> 1. http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=171
> 2. [crystal report dynamic column and .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776129/crystal-report-dynamic-column-and-net)
> 3. [Can I Move fields in a Crystal Report to another position when run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681959/can-i-move-fields-in-a-crystal-report-to-another-position-when-run/)
> 4. Using cross-tabs.